# What happens to my in-game mail when my World of Warcraft account is frozen?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I don't use monthly subscriptions in WoW so I'm always aware when I'm buying more game time so I constantly determine if it's worthwhile to toss down $15 again and again.  As a result, I'll occasionally let my account be frozen for a couple weeks at a time until I feel like playing again.

With my many alts, I abuse the mail system for cheap communal bank slots, and I have a few dozen mails filled with this or that going between my characters.  My account has lapsed before while I've had stuff in transit, but I never bothered to pay attention to what happened to my items.  What happens to my in-game mails when my account is in a "Frozen" state?  Does the 30-day mail timer keep ticking down until they rot or are returned?  Does the clock freeze?  Would I still get auction-house mail for a successful sale, etc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a terrible habit of not checking my mail before freezing my account, and I can confirm the clock stops for no man: after 30 days, the mail is returned, and after 30 more days, it's deleted.

Besides the clock, the mailbox works as if you were still subscribed. Your characters, for all intents and purposes, are considered merely "logged off" until you explicitly delete them, so mail will still be delivered even while your account is frozen.

Comment: This is true for if you mail your bank alt, bounce mail. It then sits on the bank alt there for 30 days and then bounces and sits on the mail for 30 days and then gets deleted.